# Как сделать локальное зеркало репозитория для flatpak?

Tags: linux, администрирование, flatpak

Немного поковырял эту технологию и возник подобный вопрос. Желательно, чтобы кэшировалось средствами `apt-cacher-ng`, но и от `rsync` не откажусь. Знаю про грязный хак в виде `mitm` - но это сильно дикий костыль.

Comment: судя по изложенному, например, [здесь](https://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2017/02/10/maintaining-a-flatpak-repository/), любого http-клиента должно быть достаточно для скачивания содержимого «репозитория». а для раздачи достаточно любого http-сервера.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, изучу. Тогда отпишусь.

Comment: TODO. Есть возможность поднять self-hosted репу. Вполне подходит. https://github.com/flatpak/flat-manager . Поковыряю как будет время.